# Drawing auxiliary lines in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

In latex, how do I draw an auxiliary line, a line that is partitioned into many little lines, from one point to another point with tikz?

I know how to use regular lines, but not auxiliary.

Comment: Hi, what do you mean "auxiliary line", do you have photo or example?

Comment: `\draw[dashed] (A)--(B)`

Comment: Double posts: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69237926/drawing-auxiliary-lines-in-tikz

Answer (score 3):

Use one of the `\draw` options `dashed`, `dotted`, `densely dashed`, `loosely dotted` etc. You can also define your own patterns, see the `tikz` manual, section 15.3.2 *Graphic Parameters: Dash Pattern*

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
Loosely dashed line: \tikz\draw[loosely dashed] (0,0) -- (5,0);

Dashed line: \tikz\draw[dashed] (0,0) -- (5,0);

Densely dashed line: \tikz\draw[densely dashed] (0,0) -- (5,0);

Loosely dotted line: \tikz\draw[loosely dotted] (0,0) -- (5,0);

Dotted line: \tikz\draw[dotted] (0,0) -- (5,0);

Densely dotted line: \tikz\draw[densely dotted] (0,0) -- (5,0);

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean this? fill a line with dots or draw a line to the end of `\linewidth` or with a fixed width, see [this link](https://latexref.xyz/_005chrulefill-_0026-_005cdotfill.html).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

Fill a line with dots: \dotfill
    
\noindent{\color{red}\dotfill} 
    
\noindent{\color{blue}\dotfill} 

Draw a line: \hrulefill
    
\noindent{\color{red}\hrulefill} 

\noindent{\color{blue}\hrulefill} 

\lipsum[2]
\vspace*{5mm}

To make a line $2$ cm long: ~\makebox[2in]{\hrulefill}
\vspace*{5mm}

To make a dotted line $2$ cm long: ~\makebox[2in]{\dotfill}
\vspace*{1cm}

\begin{flushright}
\begin{minipage}{4cm}
    \centering
    \hrulefill\\
    Signed
\end{minipage}
\end{flushright}    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=\dimexpr355pt/113\relax]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0)  grid  (10,10);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Miscellaneous

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=\dimexpr355pt/113\relax]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[lightgray,thin,dashed] (0,0)  grid  (10,10);
    \draw[thick,red] (5,5) circle (1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: At the time I wrote this answer, I assumed that it was about drawing with TikZ because most your previous questions are about drawing with TikZ.